# How to show CircularProgressIndicator in Scaffold while GridView is being loaded

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I wanted to display a single circular progress indicator at the center of the container until the images all the images get loaded from the internet. But it is not working. I tried in many ways.

```
class Category extends StatefulWidget {
  static String screenid = "Category_screen";
  @override
  _CategoryState createState() => _CategoryState();
}

class _CategoryState extends State<Category> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if(CategoryGridItems == null){
      return Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      );
    }
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                  colors: [Color(0xff1f4037), Colors.white],
                  begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                  end: Alignment.center),
            ),
            height: 300.0,
          ),
          SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 60.0,
                  ),
                  // Add Horizontal scroll here
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
                    height: 70.0,
                    color: Colors.redAccent,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: GridView.count(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                      crossAxisCount: 2,
                      crossAxisSpacing: 4,
                      mainAxisSpacing: 8,
                      childAspectRatio: 1.8,
                      padding:
                          EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0, vertical: 25.0),
                      children: <Widget>[
                        CategoryGridItems(
                          image: 'https://i.ibb.co/fxfWjyn/custom-1-2x.jpg',
                          ontapped: () {
                            Navigator.push(context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                              return CategoryGrid(
                                label: 'nature',
                                colour: Color(0xffba2828),
                                displaytext: 'Nature',
                              );
                            }));
                          },
                        ),
                        CategoryGridItems(
                          image: 'https://i.ibb.co/JsLpD25/custom-2-2x.jpg',
                          ontapped: () {
                            Navigator.push(context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                              return CategoryGrid(
                                label: 'dark_collection',
                                colour: Color(0xffba2828),
                                displaytext: 'Dark',
                              );
                            }));
                          },
                        ),
                        CategoryGridItems(
                          image: 'https://i.ibb.co/GvrzW7R/custom-8-2x.jpg',
                          ontapped: () {
                            Navigator.push(context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                              return CategoryGrid(
                                label: 'abstract_collection',
                                colour: Color(0xff646def),
                                displaytext: 'Abstract',
                              );
                            }));
                          },
                        ),
                        CategoryGridItems(
                          image: 'https://i.ibb.co/3mJ6c0J/custom-3-2x.jpg',
                          ontapped: () {
                            Navigator.push(context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                              return CategoryGrid(
                                label: 'food_collection',
                                colour: Color(0xff646def),
                                displaytext: 'Food',
                              );
                            }));
                          },
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CategoryGridItems extends StatelessWidget {
  final String image;
  final Function ontapped;

  CategoryGridItems({
    @required this.image,
    @required this.ontapped,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: ontapped,
          child: ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
              Radius.circular(8.0),
            ),
            child: Image.network(
              image,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have given `Loading` inside a Container but it is displayed inside the container. I don't want to show a blank screen instead show a Circular progress indicator.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a CircularProgressIndicator, but consider using the FadeInImage Widget:

```
FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(
  placeholder: kTransparentImage,
  image: 'https://picsum.photos/250?image=9',
);
```

To show a CircularProgressIndicator for a network image, you will need to work with an HTTP request.  IMO you should just save your time and use the code above (you may occasionally get 4xx errors, but most of the time the image should load eventually.  If not should still be ok as it will not crash your app entirely).